# The update mapping to user's update-key cannot be processed

Tags: api, linkedin-api

We took several days to receive a error message when we try to read comments to a linkedin post with the next url:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id_company}/updates/key={update_key}/update-comments?event-type=status-update

The error message is: The update mapping to user's update-key cannot be processed.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.